# Filter product category archive pages in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I'm currently working on a WordPress/WooCommerce bookstore site, that uses a custom `taxonomy.php` WooCommerce template to display sets of products by one product category called "Highlights". So, for example, `/books/product-category/highlights/best-sellers` displays products associated with the "Best Sellers" sub-category of "Highlights". What I'd like to do is add filter functionality to these archive pages to allow more fine-grained views of these product categories by a different category called "Topics". So, for example, checking a box on the "Best Sellers" page for "Art" would show Best Sellers *within* that category.

Ultimately, I'd like to do so using a `$_GET` parameter in the URL, such as `/books/product-category/highlights/best-sellers/?topic=art`. I have been experimenting with `pre_get_posts` but my results have been a bit erratic at best. Here is what I have tried thus far in `functions.php`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_product_topic');

function filter_product_topic($query) {

    if( is_admin() ) return;
    $tax_query = $query->get('tax_query');

    if( isset($_GET['topic']) ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy'       => 'product_cat',
            'field'   => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $_GET['topic'],
            'operator'   => 'IN'
        );
    }
    $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
}
```

As a very basic test, this seems to work for the main archive query, but it seems to have an adverse effect on the rest of the template, and looks to disrupt a different query on the page for a hero element that shows a carousel of different products. For those more familiar with WooCommerce, I'm wondering if there's a better way for me to achieve the desired result *and* to only impact the main archive product query, and not any others that might exist in the template?

Thanks for any assistance here, and please let me know if my question or related details are unclear in any way.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the main missing thing should be to use [`is_main_query()` `WP_Query` method](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) this way:

```
if( ! $query->is_main_query() ) return;
```

---

Alternatively instead of using WordPress `pre_get_posts` filter hook, in Woocommerce for a **Tax query** you can use **dedicated** `woocommerce_product_query_tax_query` filter hook, that already include `is_main_query()` Wordpress WP_Query method.

This hook is part of woocommerce dedicated `WC_Query` class. So try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'filter_product_topic', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_topic( $tax_query, $query ) {
    // Only on Product Category archives pages
    if( is_admin() || ! is_product_category()  ) return $tax_query;

    // The taxonomy for Product Categories
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

    if( isset( $_GET['topic'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['topic'] )) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy'       => $taxonomy,
            'field'   => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array( $_GET['topic'] ),
            'operator'   => 'IN'
        );
    }

    return $tax_query;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: thank you for your response; unfortunately, these routes still aren't working for me, and I suspect it's due to how `taxonomy.php` is customized (this is a site I inherited, and my familiarity w/ WooCommerce is limited.) If you don't mind, I'm providing links here to a couple gists with the code behind `taxonomy.php` as well as a file linked by the template. Any thoughts on how to get the filter working? (1) taxonomy: https://gist.github.com/nickpish/381f458d1ef4deb84e9306a7e3b4f243; (2) resources_category.php: https://gist.github.com/nickpish/d07aafa3d804d39772660378d0a94e3c

Comment: @nickpish I will have a look on this to see if I can find out where the problem is and to get a convenient and working workaround.

Comment: thanks so much for the help- it's greatly appreciated! I've been having the hardest time getting this working! Please let me know if you should need any more info.

Comment: I'm actually on a plane right now w/ slow wifi, but I just sent you a message via Skype! Thanks again.

Comment: @nickpish I had a look to your files, but I am not used to genesis powered themes and this files seems to be customized for some "Wooc" plugin. So I really can't test anything and not able to help you on that for now.

Comment: @loictheaztec- thanks for taking a look; there is the added dimension that it's a Genesis theme, and I wasn't even aware of the additional plugin- too many variables...